# Unable to Show background image from static resource in Lightning web component

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I am unable to show background image from static resource in Lightning web component,Kindly help me on this, Advance thanks

CSS:

```css
.background_img {
    background-image: url('/resource/1602781955000/NCRN_HeroImage');
}
```

Html:

```html
<div class="background_img">{backgroundUrl}</div>
```

JS:

```js
import { LightningElement, track, wire, api } from 'lwc';

import backgroundUrl from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/NCRN_HeroImage";

export default class NcrnHeroComponent extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

  get backgroundStyle() {
        return `height:50rem;background-image:url(${backgroundUrl})`;
    }

}
```

Comment: If possible ,Kindly suggest any other alternative to add background image from static resource for lightning web component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have already defined the getter for background style.

```
get backgroundStyle() {
    return `height:50rem; background-image:url(${backgroundUrl})`;
}
```

Just use that to define the style on the div.

```
<div style={backgroundStyle}></div>
```